# extracting a substring between two slash characters of an NSString representing a URL

Tags: ios, nsstring, extract

I have an NSString object which is the URL of a webpage that contains a long random group of characters.  I want to extract the characters contained between the only two slashes in the string.  Can anybody help me to do this?  For example, I would like to extract the sting between somewebpage.com and nextlink in the following string.

[Link](https://somewebpage.com/687474703a2f2f696e74726163782e636174686179706163696669632e636/nextlink/home).

Comment: what you want exactly? give an example

Comment: i am loading a webpage that is protected in a UIWebView.  Everytime I log on, there is a massive group of random characters between the home address and the link.  I need to extract this group so I can create links that change each time you log in.  So basically if I can just extract the characters indicated above, I can append this to other links and bypass this security issue.

Comment: somewebpage.com and nextlink mentioned as example are known to you ?

Comment: Are all the strings in same format? somepage - then the numbers - then the text you want?

Comment: sorry, i no it sounds confusing.  for example i want to log onto a webpage called somewebpage.com  after entering a username and password, i want to go to a link called somewebpage.com/anotherpage  except because of the security, the link is actually somewebpage.com/a;lkdflkadjflakdjflkjadfkj/anotherpage with all those random characters changing each time.  If I can extract them I can append them to my links each time programatically.

Comment: yes, all same format and yes, those links known to me.  it's just the stuff in the middle that changes everytime you log in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    NSString *data = @"https://somewebpage.com/687474703a2f2f696e74726163782e636174686179706163696669632e636/nextlink/home";
    data = [data substringFromIndex:[data rangeOfString:@"somewebpage.com/"].location + [@"somewebpage.com/" length]];
    data = [data substringToIndex:[data rangeOfString:@"/nextlink"].location];

    NSLog(@"%@",data);
```

*NOTE : I assume somewebpage.com and nextlink are known component of your URL* .So replace that part here

Answer (score 0):

```
NSRange rr2 = [content rangeOfString:@"https://somewebpage.com/"];
    NSRange rr3 = [content rangeOfString:@"/nextlink/home"];
    int lengt = rr3.location - rr2.location - rr2.length;
    int location = rr2.location + rr2.length;
    NSRange aa;
    aa.location = location;
    aa.length = lengt;
    theString = [theString substringWithRange:aa];
```